# После включения ProGuard , приложение вылетает в одной из активности

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-gradle

Включил **ProGuard** , исправил предупреждения и ошибки при компиляции, настроил `proguard-rules.pro` , но при открытии одной из активити внутри приложения, она открывается и через некоторое время приложение крашится.

логи ошибки:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.myapp.pro, PID: 6416
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                                                at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:171)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:589)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18798)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18798)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18798)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18798)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18798)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18798)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:887)
                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18798)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2648)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2364)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
                                                                                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
07-04 18:25:53.661 6416-6416/com.myapp.pro E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:168)
                                                                                    ... 52 more
```

файл `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes *Annotation*
#Keep Anotations
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-dontoptimize

-keep class com.myapp.pro.model.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService
-keep class com.myapp.pro.ui.activity.ChatActivity.MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder

-keep class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth implements InternalTokenProvider

-keep class com.myapp.pro.model.MyFirebaseMessagingService
-keep class com.myapp.pro.model.PlaybackService
-keep class com.myapp.pro.model.TimerPauseMusicService
-keep class com.myapp.pro.component.**{ *; }
-keep class * implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
-keep public class com.myapp.pro.ui.activity.Splash2Activity
-keep public class com.myapp.pro.ui.PlayerView
-keep public class com.myapp.pro.ui.activity.ChatActivity
-keep public class com.myapp.pro.ui.activity.SignInActivity
-keep public class com.myapp.pro.ui.activity.ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity
-keep public class com.myapp.pro.ui.PlayerView extends RelativeLayout
-keep public interface OnClickListener

-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }


-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
#-keep public class * implements View.OnClickListener

-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

# Keep all classes with a native method

-keepclassmembers class * {
   public static native <methods>;
   private static native <methods>;
   static native <methods>;
   private native <methods>;
   native <methods>;
}

-keepattributes Signature
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
  public static **[] values();
  public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep class com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.app.Application.** { *; }
-keep class android.app.Activity.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class android.view.** { *; }
-keep class android.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.**
-keep class com.mikepenz.iconics.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.mikepenz.iconics.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.firebase.ui.database.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
```

Непойму, что еще нужно сказать ProGuard'у, чтоб он не трогал какие-либо классы и методы. Пробывал прописать всю активити в `proguard-rules.pro`, таким образом:

```
-keep class com.myapp.pro.ui.activity.ChatActivity
```

но результатов и изменений это не дало. Буду очень признателен, кто поможет выявить и решить эту проблему.

Comment: поробуйте: -keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Антон, я вижу вы неплохо продвинулись) Это вы молодец. Так же я виже по ошибке, что ему не хватает ViewHodler-а. Ставлю меховую шапку, что у вас Viewholder находиться в одном файле с Adapter-ом. Если так, вынесите холдер в отдельный файл.

Comment: Вынес холдер в отдельный класс. Всё равно крашило).. Дописал к каждому методу который был в активности и в холдере аннотацию '@Keep' , и вуаля.. всё открылось. Но я точно не уверен, что аннотации к классам и методам '@Keep' вообще работают...

Comment: есть еще одна ошибка, касающаяся открытия айтема из метода на вход которому идёт (MenuItem) . Внутри Intent, который должен перекинуть пользователя в GooglePlay на страницу приложения. Как исправить его, пока тоже разобраться не могу. Есть логи ошибки. Не знаю, создать еще вопрос, или обновить этот?

Comment: public void rateapp(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(R.string.googleplay + getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

Comment: ах если бы я знал)) этот зверь мне не знаком! Найдете решение, обязательно напишите

Comment: решения не нашел. Переделывал вызов интента даже не назначая метод через onClick, а напрямую написав в методе onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)... Но всё равно возникали краши.. и ругательство в логах на то, что активити не действительна и т.п.. Самое интересное, что другие кнопки работали из меню приложения.. Видать дело в самом Intent..

Answer (score 0):

Попробйте еще пометить ресурсы которые используются в этом Holder через аттрибуты tools:keep (подробнее https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-resources)